# Enable button when wx.TextCtrl is clicked in

Tags: python, wxpython, wxtextctrl

I have a dialog box (with multiple editable text fields and buttons) and want to activate one of buttons when any one of text field boxes is clicked in. Like following is with default value of `0.56` and once user click in that box, a separate button should be enabled. Any suggestions?

```
wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Reach Slope", (40, 170))
self.reachslope = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, value=str(0.56), pos=(150, 165), size=(75,25))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind to the `wx.TextCtrl()` event `EVT_SET_FOCUS` which fires when the textctrl receives focus and use that event to enable the button.
Here's a poorly constructed example:

```
import wx

def on0Focus(event):
    button0.Enable()
    button1.Disable()
    print "text0 widget received focus!"

def on1Focus(event):
    button1.Enable()
    button0.Disable()
    print "text1 widget received focus!"

app = wx.App()

frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, 'Set Focus Test', size=(500,100))

dummy = wx.TextCtrl(frame, wx.ID_ANY, size=(1,1), pos=(10,1))#Prevents text0 getting focus on Show()
text0 = wx.TextCtrl(frame, wx.ID_ANY, size=(345,25), pos=(10,10))
text0.SetValue("123456")
button0 = wx.Button(frame,-1, "Zero",pos=(400,10))

text1 = wx.TextCtrl(frame, wx.ID_ANY, size=(345,25), pos=(10,40))
text1.SetValue("abcdef")
button1 = wx.Button(frame,-1, "One", pos=(400,40))

text0.Bind(wx.EVT_SET_FOCUS, on0Focus)
text1.Bind(wx.EVT_SET_FOCUS, on1Focus)
button0.Disable()
button1.Disable()

frame.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

[image]